# Drawer navigator nested inside stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a Drawer nested inside of the stack. Unable to implement the back button using it. Can anyone provide a clean solution to resolve this =(

I want to show back button on top on iOS and on android navigate to last screen using hardware back button.

**Drawer Navigator**

```
/* @flow */

import React from "react";
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import Home from "./components/home/";
import SplashPage from "./components/splashscreen/";
import SideBar from "./components/sidebar";
import Contact from "./components/Contact/";



const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
   Home: { screen: Home },
    Contact: { screen: Contact},
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    },
  initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    drawerPosition: 'right',
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);



export default Drawer;
```

**Stack Navigator**

```
/* @flow */

import React from "react";

import { Platform } from "react-native";
import { Root } from "native-base";
import { StackNavigator} from "react-navigation";
import Drawer from "./Drawer";
import Contact from "./components/Contact"
import Register from "./components/Register"
import Home from "./components/home/";

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
       Home: { screen: Home },
        Register: {screen: Register},
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
           headerMode: Platform.OS == "android" ? "none" : "float",
        header: (navigation) => ({
            left: (
                <Button
                  title="Back"
                  onPress={ () => navigation.goBack() }  
                />
              )
          })
    }
);

export default () =>
    <Root>
        <AppNavigator />
    </Root>;
```

Comment: So, do you want to access your Drawer in every screen? Or only on a particular screen? Or you only want your Drawer in your Homescreen but not in other screens?

Answer (score 0):

Use `null` as a parameter when call `goBack` function like this:

```
navigation.goBack(null)
```